# Is Create method or Update faster?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm using rails 3.2.11 and ruby 1.9.3.
I have a slow page and I know I have many ways to optimize it. Currently I am focused on the method update_attributes.

Here is my code:

```
def create
  @user = current_user
  @demo = @user.demos.new

  race_ethnicity_response = []
  params[:race_ethnicity_response].each do |response, value|
    race_ethnicity_response << response if value != '0'
  end

  params[:demo][:race_ethnicity_response] = race_ethnicity_response.join(', ')[0, 254]
  @demo.update_attributes(params[:demo])
end
```

Or should I use something like build and save or create?

```
@demo = @user.demos.build
...
@demo.save!
```

Or

```
@users.demos.create!(params[demo])
```

I am curious which is faster. I know if it save 2ms then I should use the one which is more code correct/readable.

Comment: It doesn't matter. I'm willing to bet they'll issue identical SQL commands

Comment: update_attributes and save may produce the same sql, but What if  update_attributes do a lot of checks before making the sql call. Or other things.

Comment: How slow is the page?  Can you post your logs from the console showing the speeds?

Comment: I'm using mini-profiler and sometimes that part can take 230ms

Comment: update_attribute and save are the same :). but is it better is just use create! method?

Answer (score 0):

On a small operation like this you aren't going to see much of a performance difference. Go for readability + maintainability. The code above does seem a little scattered, particularly the middle block. Here is a straightforward approach although I may be missing something related to the params[:race_ethnicity_response] loop.

```
@demo = Demo.new(:params)
@demo.race_ethnicity_response = race_ethnicity_response.reject{|i| i == 0 }.join(', ')[0, 254]
current_user.demos << @demo
```

Comment: for race_ethnicity_response I need to remove all the '0' first

Comment: updated. wasn't able to test it but you get the idea.

Comment: Doesn't "race_ethnicity_response" is a hash